# Use sdk problem

Tags: android

How to set `targetsdkversion` for 1.5. I developing projects based on eclipse id when I try to set `targetSdkVersion` in manifest it showing error.

Comment: show how you exactly do it in your manifest file and also post the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

and compile against 1.6.
It will give you a warning thought.

Comment: if i run this application on android 1.5 emulator it is showing error of drawable elements

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Project in Eclipse there is an option to set the target version for your application. This will also be changeable in a preferences box somewhere (probably the Project menu). It will only show you installed versions however (on mine I only have the option to target 2.1 as I haven't bothered installing any other versions).